# How to add a member to rapidjson whose value is NULL?

Tags: rapidjson

Is there a neat way to add a member to a RapidJson document object?

As a workaround, I added a random string to the document and then set it to NULL.

```
  rapidJson::Document doc;
  doc.SetObject();
  doc.AddMember("MemberWhoseValueIsNULL", "randomString");
  doc["MemberWhoseValueIsNULL"].SetNull();
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
  rapidJson::Document doc(kObjectType);
  doc.AddMember("MemberWhoseValueIsNULL", rapidJson::Value());
```

Comment: To be more explicit, you could use:

rapidjson::Value(rapidjson::Type::kNullType)